# Using capture group $1 to access object's key value

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects

aBelow, I am trying to access the HTML entity value, which is stored in the object as shown below by defining the key using regular expressions. However, I get "Batman undefined Robin" as opposed to "Batman & Robin". Could somebody explain to me why i am getting undefined as opposed to the object's key value property? Thank you!

```
function convertHtmlEntities ( str ) {

    // Object containing all the key value pair of HTML entities.
    var htmlEntities = {
        "&": "&amp;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        '"': "&quot;",
        "'": "&apos;"
    };

    // Regular expression for replacing the items mentioned above with the
    // appropriate HTML entities.
    console.log( str.replace( /([\&\<\>\"\'])+/, htmlEntities['$1'] ) );
    return str.replace( /([\&\<\>\"\'])+/, "$1" );
}

convertHtmlEntities("Batman & Robin"); // Should return "Batman &amp; Robin"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to `String.replace()`:

```
str.replace( /([\&\<\>\"\'])+/, function(match){
    return htmlEntities[match];
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I figured it out roughly 15 minutes after posting this that you can also pass in a function into String.replace()

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
str.replace( /([\&\<\>\"\'])+/, htmlEntities[RegExp.$1]
```

This will return (at least it does for me):

```
"Batman &amp; Robin"
```

Also, be aware that this is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features), its functionality might be removed by browsers as-and-when.